# Login to admin pending forever with Valet+

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.3, slowbackend

I'm using **Valet+** on **MacOS** and have tweaked the **`Nginx`** and **`PHP`** configs to increase **execution time** etc.

Doing a fresh install, the frontend will load, **slow at first**, but **fast after subsequent reloads**, as expected.

The **admin login** screen is the same, **loads slow**, then **fast afterwards**.

Now, when I enter the **correct credentials**, the request to login is pending for **20+ minutes**.

I have all **caches enabled**, except `compiled_config` and I have `redis` setup for sessions and caching.

There are is no data in the store either.

What is causing this never-ending load time for the admin?

Comment: try deleting the cookies